# Yunga DIRegEx - caseless и кириллица

Tags: delphi

Вопрос по Yunga DiRegExpr (Delphi). Проблема с caseless и кириллицей. Вначале регулярки это `(?i)` означает, что следует вести поиск символов без учета регистра. Но если текст кириллический, то параметр `(?i)` не работает. Можно ли как-то DiRegExpr заставить не учитывать регистр и для кириллицы? Есть в справке что-то про юникод, но не могу заставить работать:

```
\p{Greek}
\P{Han}
\P{Cyrillic}
```

Регулярка:

```
\P{Cyrillic}(?i)ново
```

не работает, слово "Ново" не находит.

Comment: Delphi XE3 + DiRegEx 8.33

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39080758/327083

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вам надо чтобы он определял любую букву в любом регистре, то используйте `\p{L}`, например `\p{L}ово` -> 'ново', 'Ново', 'Dово' и т.п.
2. Если вы хотите только кириллицу, то: `\p{Cyrillic}`, например `\p{Cyrillic}ово` -> 'ново' и 'Ново', но не 'Dово'.

[Пример - тут.](https://regex101.com/r/pB9iW2/1)

Обратите внимание, что **p** - строчная, а не прописная как у вас.

Comment: Нет, Вы не поняли. Надо, чтобы определялось "Ново" и "ново"
по идее вот регулярка: "(?i)ново", но она не работает

Comment: Во всех регексах, с которыми я работал, флаг **i** влияет только на латиницу. Но регекс из пункта 2: `\p{Cyrillic}ово` как раз и будет определять "Ново" и "ново", т.к. `\p{Cyrillic}` - это любая буква из кириллицы. Я же даже пример сделал - перейдите по ссылке.

Comment: Так мне не нужна ЛЮБАЯ буква из кириллицы, нужена именно "Н" или "н" в данном конкретном случае.
Получается, что только через: rexp.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess];

Comment: Если вам нужна только "Н" или "н", то в чём проблема сделать `[Нн]ово`? Тут вообще не нужно никакого **i**. Если всё слово без учёта регистра, то можно, конечно, `[Нн][Оо][Вв][Оо]`, но разумнее наверное будет действительно через `[coCaseLess]`, если оно работает с кириллицей.

Comment: Мне нужно вообще отключить регистрозависимость. Текст очень длинный и там может быть не только Н, а и любая буква кириллицы.

Comment: в общем, сделал так:
    if ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?i)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?is)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?si)') then
      rexp.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess];

Answer (score 1):

Если легального способа искать без учета регистра не найдется, то сделай функцию, которая превращает регулярку `ново` в `[Нн][Оо][Вв][Оо]`. Не думаю, что скорость от этого пострадает.

Comment: Сделал так:

if ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?i)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?is)') or ContainsText(MatchPattern, '(?si)') then rexp.CompileOptions := [coCaseLess];